# Swift: Trying to execute two functions with delegation

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to execute two functions in another view by pressing two buttons. Each button should call one of the functions, that is passed on through delegation. 
But it seems like when I am pressing one of the buttons they execute both functions of the protocol simultaneously. 
Only when I comment/remove one function it works.

The protocol:

```
protocol ManipulateSectionDelegate {
    func addSection()
    func removeSection()
}
```

The MainView:
Here are the functions that should get called, when pressing the buttons in the second View

```
extension MainViewController: ManipulateSectionDelegate{

    @objc func showSettingsView(){
        let settingsController = SettingsViewController()
        settingsController.delegateManipuplateSection = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsController, animated: true)
    }

    func addSection(){
        semesterList.append(Semester.init(subject: [], done: false))
        subjectTableView.reloadData()
        print(semesterList)
    }

    func removeSection(){
        semesterList.removeLast()
        subjectTableView.reloadData()
        print(semesterList)
    }

}
```

The second View:

```
class SettingsViewController:UIViewController{

    var delegateManipuplateSection: ManipulateSectionDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addSectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addSectionButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

        addSectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeSectionButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
}


extension SettingsViewController{

    @objc func addSectionButtonPressed(){
        delegateManipuplateSection?.addSection()
    }

    @objc func removeSectionButtonPressed(){
        delegateManipuplateSection?.removeSection()
    }    
}
```

Even though each button is connected to a different function and should execute only one of them, both get executed. 
Is this a situation where I would have to use observers and notifications? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connected two actions to one *same* button

```
    addSectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addSectionButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    addSectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeSectionButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```